# How can I upload large image files to Wasabi more quickly in node js?

Tags: node.js, express, aws-sdk, wasabi, wasabi-hot-cloud-storage

`enter code here`I am using "aws-sdk": "^2.1551.0" npm for file uploads, I've noticed that uploading a large image file (10 MB) to a Wasabi bucket takes more than 15 seconds. How can I make the upload process faster?

I aim to achieve uploads of large files within 3 seconds. Furthermore, I seek clarification on the difference between aws-sdk and aws-sdk/client-s3. Will using aws-sdk/client-s3 result in faster uploads? If not, could you provide a suitable solution?

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
  const settings = await Settings.findOne({})
  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: settings.accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: settings.secretAccessKey,
    region: settings.region, 
    endpoint: settings.endpoint,
  });

const params = {
    Bucket: settings.bucketName,
    Key: `${setting.bucketName}/photos/${DIR}/${newFileName}`,
    Body: file.buffer,
    ContentType: file.mimetype,
  };

  s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error uploading photo:', err);
      return next(new ErrorHandler(err, 200));
    } else {
      console.log('Photo uploaded successfully.', data);
    }
  });
```

Comment: "*I aim to achieve uploads of large files within 3 seconds*" - What's your upload rate? `10MB+ / 3s = 3MBs+`. Does your ISP offer you this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.